# How to always show the first TAB

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the first tab always whenever the page load, which is the "Details" tab, any idea to do it? I have tried added JavaScript which runs on pageload, but it didn't work out as I wish.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Details')">Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Reviews')">Reviews</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="Details" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Details</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Reviews" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Reviews</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function getFirstChildWithTagName(evt, tagName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName) return element.childNodes[i];
  }
}

function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.tablinks:first').addClass('active');
});
```

Tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
function LoadFunction() {
  var mybtn = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[0];
  mybtn.click();
}
window.onload = LoadFunction();
```

Comment: _"but it didn't work out as I wish"_ — What are you expecting ? What is not happening ?

Comment: I found this working quiet well – https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/26sp9ycs/

Comment: please check this one https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to add style elements that mimic button click in the initial HTML.

Add active class to tablink button

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'Details')">Details</a></li>
```

Add display style to tab content

```
<div id="Details" class="tabcontent" style="display:block">
```

Hope that helps

Comment: this works, thanks! I only add the display:block and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.tab li:first-child').find('a').addClass('active');
    $('.tabcontent').hide();
    $('.tabcontent:first-child').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tablinks:first').addClass('active');
});
```

or add jQuery library to your code

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve you goal with small correction in your code. Please not that you are using both JQuery and JavaScript syntax so I assume you have included JQuery in your code.

**html**

```
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Details')">Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Reviews')">Reviews</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="Details" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Details</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Reviews" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Reviews</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>
```

**script**

```
function getFirstChildWithTagName(evt, tagName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName) return element.childNodes[i];
  }
}

function openTab(elem, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  console.log(elem)
  $(elem[0]).addClass("active");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  var elem = $('.tablinks:first');
  var tabName = "Details"
  openTab(elem,tabName);
});
```

plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/G8Kw76nvK4Xsz8oY6fRQ?p=preview